# Spring-ws not preserving CDATA in the soap response

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

**Context**

I am using Spring WS for producing web service as mentioned in the link: https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/. However, when I am sending xml content wrapped with CDATA I get the response escaped and this is causing problem for non-java clients as they want element content to be within CDATA and everything unescaped.

**I have tried**

SaajSoapMessageFactory and
AxiomSoapMessageFactory (with payload caching set to false)

**Configuration**

WebServiceConfig.java

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext 
applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}

@Bean
public AxiomSoapMessageFactory messageFactory() {
    /*SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
    messageFactory.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.SOAP_11);

    messageFactory.afterPropertiesSet();*/

    AxiomSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new AxiomSoapMessageFactory();
    //messageFactory.
    messageFactory.setPayloadCaching(false);
    messageFactory.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.SOAP_11);
    return messageFactory;
}

@Bean(name = "countries")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema 
countriesSchema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new 
DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CountriesPort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-
producing-web-service");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}

@Bean
public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("countries.xsd"));
}
```

**CountryRepository.java**

```
@Component
public class CountryRepository {
private static final Map<String, Country> countries = new HashMap<>();

@PostConstruct
public void initData() {
    Country spain = new Country();
    spain.setName("Spain");
    spain.setCapital("<![CDATA[<a>Madrid</a>]]>");
    spain.setCurrency(Currency.EUR);
    spain.setPopulation(46704314);

    countries.put(spain.getName(), spain);

    Country poland = new Country();
    poland.setName("Poland");
    poland.setCapital("Warsaw");
    poland.setCurrency(Currency.PLN);
    poland.setPopulation(38186860);

    countries.put(poland.getName(), poland);

    Country uk = new Country();
    uk.setName("United Kingdom");
    uk.setCapital("London");
    uk.setCurrency(Currency.GBP);
    uk.setPopulation(63705000);

    countries.put(uk.getName(), uk);
}

public Country findCountry(String name) {
    Assert.notNull(name, "The country's name must not be null");
    return countries.get(name);
}
}
```

**Soap UI Request**

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      xmlns:gs="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <gs:getCountryRequest>
         <gs:name>Spain</gs:name>
      </gs:getCountryRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Soap UI response**

```html
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:getCountryResponse xmlns:ns2="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service">
         <ns2:country>
            <ns2:name>Spain</ns2:name>
            <ns2:population>46704314</ns2:population>
            <ns2:capital>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;a>Madrid&lt;/a>]]&gt;</ns2:capital>
            <ns2:currency>EUR</ns2:currency>
         </ns2:country>
      </ns2:getCountryResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Expected response**

```html
<![CDATA[<a>Madrid</a>]]>
```

**Question**

Can anyone suggestwhat I am doing wrong and how to correct this behavior?

Thanks in advance.